# Divide string by line break or period with Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string:

```
"""Hello. It's good to meet you.
My name is Bob."""
```

I'm trying to find the best way to split this into a list divided by periods and linebreaks:

```
["Hello", "It's good to meet you", "My name is Bob"]
```

I'm pretty sure I should use regular expressions, but, having no experience with them, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need regex.

```
>>> txt = """Hello. It's good to meet you.
... My name is Bob."""
>>> txt.split('.')
['Hello', " It's good to meet you", '\nMy name is Bob', '']
>>> [x for x in map(str.strip, txt.split('.')) if x]
['Hello', "It's good to meet you", 'My name is Bob']
```

Answer (score 3):

For your example, it would suffice to split on dots, optionally followed by whitespace (and to ignore empty results):

```
>>> s = """Hello. It's good to meet you.
... My name is Bob."""
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"\.\s*", s)
['Hello', "It's good to meet you", 'My name is Bob', '']
```

In real life, you'd have to handle `Mr. Orange`, `Dr. Greene` and `George W. Bush`, though...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = """Hello. It's good to meet you.
... My name is Bob."""
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'[^\s\.][^\.\n]+')
>>> p.findall(s)
['Hello', "It's good to meet you", 'My name is Bob']
>>> s = "Hello. #It's good to meet you # .'"
>>> p.findall(s)
['Hello', "#It's good to meet you # "]
```

Comment: In ``"Hello. #It's good to meet you  #  .' your regex catch ``['Hello', "It's good to meet you  #  "]``

Answer (score 1):

You can use this split

```
re.split(r"(?<!^)\s*[.\n]+\s*(?!$)", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine:

```
re.findall('(?=\S)[^.\n]+(?<=\S)',su)
```