# Python - Print Each Sentence On New Line

Tags: python, loops, newline

Per the subject, I'm trying to print each sentence in a string on a new line. With the current code and output shown below, what's the syntax to return "Correct Output" shown below?

**Code**

```
sentence = 'I am sorry Dave. I cannot let you do that.'

def format_sentence(sentence):
    sentenceSplit = sentence.split(".")
    for s in sentenceSplit:
        print s + "."
```

**Output**

```
I am sorry Dave.
 I cannot let you do that.
.
None
```

**Correct Output**

```
I am sorry Dave.
I cannot let you do that.
```

Comment: Hint: Sentences are separated by more than periods.

Comment: It has already been answered .. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618149/divide-string-by-line-break-or-period-with-python-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
def format_sentence(sentence) :
    sentenceSplit = filter(None, sentence.split("."))
    for s in sentenceSplit :
        print s.strip() + "."
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your implementation. First, as Jarvis points out in his answer, if your delimiter is the first or last character in your string or if two delimiter characters are right next to each other, `None` will be inserted into your array. To fix this, you need to filter out the `None` values. Also, instead of using the `+` operator, use formatting instead.

```
def format_sentence(sentences):
    sentences_split = filter(None, sentences.split('.'))
    for s in sentences_split:
        print '{0}.'.format(s.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by ". " instead of ".", then print each line with an additional "." until the last one, which will have a "." already.

```
def format_sentence(sentence):
    sentenceSplit = sentence.split(". ")
    for s in sentenceSplit[:-1]:
        print s + "."
    print sentenceSplit[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def format_sentence(sentence):
    print(sentence.replace('. ', '.\n'))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.