# Print Each Sentence On New Line

Tags: python

I have a text like this in a text file

```
Long sleeve wool coat in black. Breast pocket.
```

and I want an output where every sentence is printed in the next line something like this.

```
Long sleeve wool coat in black.

Breast pocket.
```

I tried the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167881/python-print-each-sentence-on-new-line) but as it was asked it's giving the output as

```
Long sleeve wool coat in black.

Breast pocket.

None
```

and also I have to do this to multiple text files reading from the original file I have to overwrite that file in this way breaking up the lines. But when I try doing that only None is getting written to it not the existing lines.

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Caveat: It's difficult to distinguish between a period as the end of the sentence and a period marking an abbreviation/acronym like "Mr." or "F.B.I.".

Comment: How are you calling this function? Please share your attempt

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy You could say that a period at the end of a sentence is followed by a space, but 'Mr.' is usually also.

Comment: Right—there's a lot of literature on how to properly do [sentence segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
in_s = 'Long sleeve wool coat in black. Breast pocket.'
in_s += ' '
out = in_s.split('. ')[:-1]
print('.\n'.join(out))
```

---

Explanation:

- `in_s += ' '` add a space at the end of the string so that it ends in `'. `` like any other sentence.
- `...in_s.split('. ')...` split the text wherever there is a period followed by a space (`'. '`).
- `...[:-1]` remove the last value, which, if the text ends in a period and a space, will be `None`
- `...'\n.join(out)` seperate the values with a period and newline before printing.

Comment: It gives me extra space at the starting of the second line

Comment: still, it's giving me the extra space from the second line

Comment: @the_guy Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
s = 'Long sleeve wool coat in black. Breast pocket.'
print(s.replace('. ', '.\n'))
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that way.

Comment: @Jan You are right, nltk should be a better solution.

Comment: @Jan I know, my answer does the same. (New line at `Mr.` but not at `U.S.A` since there is no space after the periods.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favour and use [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) instead of regular expressions or even a simple `str.split()`:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

string = "Long sleeve wool coat in black. Breast pocket. Mr. Donald Trump is the president of the U.S.A."

for sent in sent_tokenize(string):
    print(sent)
```

Which yields

```
Long sleeve wool coat in black.
Breast pocket.
Mr. Donald Trump is the president of the U.S.A.
```

This approach most likely works even for edge cases while most others won't.